# how to install sdk Android with titanium

Tags: android, sdk, installation, titanium

I download the last version of titanium but I can't add sdk Android , how do that I download sdk but the problem still here (Althoug I download sdk, the window shows an message that an it can't find the sdk) I read one sentence which maybe the solutioin of this problem the sentence is : "For Studio 3.2.0 and prior, to setup the platform SDKs, use the Studio Dashboard view as described in the Legacy Setup". Maybe I have to use Studio Dashboard for add sdk . Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways.

**Method 1**

1. Open Titanium Studio
2. Click on the dashboard button in your Titanium Studio
3. A new page will be opened as shown in figure 1

[image: Method 1]
4. Click on Android SDK. Here in my case, I have already configured Android SDK properly. That is why the icon shows **green** otherwise it will display **red** just like Tizen SDK.

5. It will ask you to download the SDK. Please select the required SDKS and download them.

**Method 2**

It is applicable only if you have downloaded Android SDK separately.

1. Open Titanium Studio
2. Open preferences from Window->Preferences
3. Select Studio->Platforms->Android (See Picture 2)

[image: Method 2]

4. Browse the path of Android SDK using the browse button
5. Click the OK button

*Do not forget to add the path of android-sdk/tools and android-sdk/platform-tools into your environment variables*

**Edit :** You can also refer to [Installing Platform SDKs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Platform_SDKs)

Hope this helped you!!

Comment: Thank you so much Anand for you efforts , I will try this then will tell you the result ;)

Comment: Please What is the name of variables I must to put of  android-sdk/tools and android-sdk/platform-tools into my environment variables

Comment: Please copy the path of tools directory in your android sdk root folder, set the environment variable (in path)

Comment: But there are two textfields : Name of variable and value of variable . In the Value of variable we put the path of directory, what I can write as name variable?

Comment: Please do not add a new value. Please refer the step 4 in the link https://sites.google.com/site/richgossweiler/home/android-development-notes/installing-the-android-sdk-on-windows. Please use your own path instead of theirs. You need to append the text to the end of path variable which is already available in the windows environment variable list

Comment: Ah ok thanks so much I will tell you the result of that .Thanks man

Comment: The issue still here :) when I browsed the path of Android sdk the window show this error : 
[Android SDK Home] No Android sdks were found under the specified SDK location ( I did all what you told me )

Comment: sure I will do it in while of time

Comment: I sent to you an email