# Titanium Studio Error: No Android SDK found

Tags: titanium

I am new to the Titanium or any other cross platform SDK. I am facing issues with the setup of Titanium Studio. I followed steps as below:

Installed NodeJS

Installed JDK 1.7 update 55 32-bit

Installed Titanium Studio 3.2.3

After first launch of Titanium Studio it installed the Titanium SDK, Alloy, Titanium CLI and other updates. In the preferences,

Titanium SDK Path

`C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\`

ANDOIRD SDK Path

`E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk`

Environment Variables are set as follows:

ANDROID_SDK

`E:\android-sdk-windows`

ANDROID_SDK_HOME

`c:\users\<UserName>`

JAVA_HOME

`C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_55`

Path

`C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin;E:\android-sdk_r22.3-windows\android-sdk-home\tools;E:\android-sdk_r22.3-windows\android-sdk-home\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs`

There are two problems here:
Alloy is not available in the new project template and
Android SDK is not available in the project template

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102573/how-to-install-sdk-android-with-titanium/23105953#23105953. May be it can help you

Answer (score 1):

On `Windows` Min JDK Version  supported is `6 (aka 1.6) rev 10` and `Max JDK Version` supported is `6 latest revision`.

The 32-bit version of the JDK is required regardless of whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows system.

On Windows, Studio contains its own JRE, meaning you do not need to install the JDK before installing or launching Studio but will need it to use the Titanium SDK.

Titanium Studio prompts you to install the JDK when installing the Android SDK from the Dashboard on Windows.

For more details please check this [link.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix)

Comment: I had JDK 1.7 update 55. Un-installed it and now I have JDK 1.6 u45 now 32-bit on Win 7 64-bit. Still Titanium Studio (3.2.3.x) showing same error in the preferences for Android.

Comment: have you checked with the command `java -version` on command prompt?

Comment: Command returned: java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: So try to downgrade the JDK to `version 1.6` .

Comment: @Swanand: As you stated above that on Windows, Studio contains its own JRE - do I still need to install JDK 1.6 and set the java path ?