# Titanium 3.x installation

Tags: titanium

I ham using 64 bit Windows 7 . I have jdk 8 64-bit installed. I could download and install Titanium Studio properly, but when downloading and setting up Android SDK from within the studio, it downloads the SDK but during installation it shows the error message "Some error occurred".

Is it possible to setup the android sdk within the studio or should I download it separately. 
Also while downloading the sdk or ndk separately, it asks me to download either 32 bit or 64 bit version, but Titanium Studio is a 32 bit application. 
What is the best way to do the installation for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to [install 32 bit JDK](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start-section-29004949_QuickStart-SystemRequirements).

From Documentation:

> For Windows, the 32-bit version of Java JDK is required regardless of
>   whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

You may install additional 32bit version of Java (without removing the 64bit) and set the system variable.

About Android SDK setup, you should look at [How to Install SDK Android with Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102573/how-to-install-sdk-android-with-titanium/23105953#23105953). I have given a detailed answer there. You can install the Android SDK from the Titanium Studio itself and it will select the proper one and don't forget to download API 10 since it is necessary to work with Titanium. You can see list of checkboxes when trying to download the sdks from the studio which denotes different Android versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will do the installations as per the instructions and hope things work out.