# Failed to install Android SDK in Titanium Studio

Tags: android, titanium

I have already installed Android 2.3.3 and also pointed the path to my Android SDK in Preferences.
But I am getting the following error:

`An Android SDK is missing. Titanium requires Android platform: 2.3.3 or above.`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have added the following environment variables: ANDROID_SDK whose  value is the path where my Android SDK is. ANDROID_NDK whose value is the also the path where my Android NDK is and JAVA_HOME, the path where my JDK is. See attached file for my error logs. Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error mean you need to install Android 2.3.3 (API 10). It's because Titanium requires API 10 to work with Android.

Try the following

1. Open Titanium Studio
2. Click on the dashboard button in your Titanium Studio
3. A new page will be opened as shown in figure 1

[image: Method 1]
4. Click on Android SDK. Here in my case, I have already configured Android SDK properly. That is why the icon shows **green** otherwise it will display **red** just like Tizen SDK.

5. It will ask you to download the SDK. Please select the required SDKS and download them. You can see the installed SDKs also. However try to select all the SDK which will fix your issue quickly. Note that it will download all the SDKs so it's little time consuming.

**Edit :** You can also refer [Install Android SDK with Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102573/how-to-install-sdk-android-with-titanium/23105953#23105953) and [Installing Platform SDKs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Platform_SDKs)

Hope this helped you!!

Comment: I have added the following environment variables: ANDROID_SDK whose value is the path where my Android SDK is. ANDROID_NDK whose value is the also the path where my Android NDK is and JAVA_HOME, the path where my JDK is. See attached file for my error logs. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: MobileSDKConfigurationProcessor_errorUpdatingAndroid in: com.appcelerator.titanium.mobile.ui.portal.processor.messages

Comment: which OS u are using?

Comment: Windows. Thank you so much for helping. I have already installed the Android SDK correctly. Im facing another problem though. I tried to run an application but Titanium Studio failed to build the application. But when I tried to run a different application  it executes successfully. I can't seem to figure out the error. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: It generates this error. Failed to run command, BUILD EPERM, operation not permitted

Comment: @Lylinette: Happy to hear that you were able to install android SDK. Did my answer help you? If yes, please mark it as accepted or answer to your own question so that it will be helpful to anyone else. Now to your new issue, I guess you are using windows 8. I am not sure of the issue, but it would be great to check whether you have admin privilege to run the app. Try to open the TiStudio as admin, then run the application. Also if you have created your workspace in restricted areas of C drive, move it to any other location.

Comment: @Anand When i run my app it gives me the following error,kindely help me out..  events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: spawn ENOENT at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11) at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34) [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8